# Context menu for JavaFX tree

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create context menu for JavaFX. This is the code that I tested. But for some reason there is no context menu when I right-click on the tree node. Can you help me to find my mistake.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItemBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
        new Employee("New Chassi", "New Datacenter"),
        new Employee("New Battery", "New Rack"),
        new Employee("New Chassi", "New Server"),
        new Employee("Anna Black", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Rodger York", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Susan Collins", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Mike Graham", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Judy Mayer", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Gregory Smith", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Jacob Smith", "Accounts Department"),
        new Employee("Isabella Johnson", "Accounts Department"));
    TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<>("MyCompany Human Resources");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        rootNode.setExpanded(true);
        for (Employee employee : employees)
        {
            TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<>(employee.getName());
            boolean found = false;
            for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren())
            {
                if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(employee.getDepartment()))
                {
                    depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                TreeItem<String> depNode = new TreeItem<>(
                    employee.getDepartment()//,new ImageView(depIcon)   // Set picture
                );
                rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
            }
        }

        stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>()
        {

            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> arg0)
            {
                // custom tree cell that defines a context menu for the root tree item
                return new MyTreeCell();
            }
        });

        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Employee
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty department;

        private Employee(String name, String department)
        {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String fName)
        {
            name.set(fName);
        }

        public String getDepartment()
        {
            return department.get();
        }

        public void setDepartment(String fName)
        {
            department.set(fName);
        }
    }

    class MyTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String>
    {
        private ContextMenu rootContextMenu;

        public MyTreeCell()
        {
            // instantiate the root context menu
            rootContextMenu
                = ContextMenuBuilder.create()
                .items(
                    MenuItemBuilder.create()
                    .text("Menu Item")
                    .onAction(
                        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Menu Item Clicked!");
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .build()
                )
                .build();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            // if the item is not empty and is a root...
            if (!empty && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)
            {
                setContextMenu(rootContextMenu);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should assign the context Menu to the TreeView instead of assigning it to the cell factory. Here is the code with the context menu working:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItemBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Test extends Application
{
    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
        new Employee("New Chassi", "New Datacenter"),
        new Employee("New Battery", "New Rack"),
        new Employee("New Chassi", "New Server"),
        new Employee("Anna Black", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Rodger York", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Susan Collins", "Sales Department"),
        new Employee("Mike Graham", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Judy Mayer", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Gregory Smith", "IT Support"),
        new Employee("Jacob Smith", "Accounts Department"),
        new Employee("Isabella Johnson", "Accounts Department"));
    TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<>("MyCompany Human Resources");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        // instantiate the root context menu
        ContextMenu rootContextMenu
            = ContextMenuBuilder.create()
            .items(
                MenuItemBuilder.create()
                .text("Menu Item")
                .onAction(
                    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Menu Item Clicked!");
                        }
                    }
                )
                .build()
            )
            .build();

        treeView.setContextMenu(rootContextMenu);

        rootNode.setExpanded(true);
        for (Employee employee : employees)
        {
            TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<>(employee.getName());
            boolean found = false;
            for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren())
            {
                if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(employee.getDepartment()))
                {
                    depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                TreeItem<String> depNode = new TreeItem<>(
                    employee.getDepartment()//,new ImageView(depIcon)   // Set picture
                );
                rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
            }
        }

        stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);


        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Employee
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty department;

        private Employee(String name, String department)
        {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String fName)
        {
            name.set(fName);
        }

        public String getDepartment()
        {
            return department.get();
        }

        public void setDepartment(String fName)
        {
            department.set(fName);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 6):

`ContextMenuBuilder` and `MenuItemBuilder` (which are used in the accepted answer) are deprecated in JavaFX 8 and will be removed in future releases.

Following an JavaFX 8 example with two items, one with icon and one without an icon:

```
MenuItem entry1 = new MenuItem("Test with Icon", graphicNode);
entry1.setOnAction(ae -> ...);
MenuItem entry2 = new MenuItem("Test without Icon");
entry2.setOnAction(ae -> ...);

myTreeView.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(entry1, entry2));
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this was 3 years ago but I hope my solution that I just found can help others like me when I was trying to find a simpler solution to this. What I found is you can just create a Label and set that as the graphic for the TreeItem. Then just set the context menu for that label, here is the code to make it work.

```
//The "" is important, without it the tree item would not appear at all
TreeItem<String> childItem = new TreeItem<>("");  

//Create a label with the string you would use for the tree item
childItem.setGraphic(new Label("TreeItem Label"));

//Add menu items for contextMenu
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

childItem.getGraphic().setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
    //Sets the context menu for the label.
    contextMenu.show(childItem.getGraphic(), e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal working example** below without the unnecessary code and deprecated functions. The solution to `.setContextMenu` to the entire tree is not really usable since different TreeItems might have different Menus. The code below uses the standard way of using the implemented factory pattern in JavaFX and allows to use of all functions from the JavaFX API:

```
package javaapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class JavaApplication2 extends Application {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    //Start a new TreeView
    TreeView<String> tv = new TreeView<>(new TreeItem<>("Root"));

    //Set the cell factory
    tv.setCellFactory(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Object p) {
            return new TreeCellWithMenu();
        }
    });

    //Fill tree with some things
    tv.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("1"));
    tv.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("2"));
    tv.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("3"));

    //Stage a new scene
    stage.setScene(new Scene(tv));

    //Show the stage
    stage.show();
}

public class TreeCellWithMenu extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {

    ContextMenu men;

    public TreeCellWithMenu() {
        //ContextMenu with one entry
        men = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Right Click"));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String t, boolean bln) {
        //Call the super class so everything works as before
        super.updateItem(t, bln);
        //Check to show the context menu for this TreeItem
        if (showMenu(t, bln)) {
            setContextMenu(men);
        }else{
            //If no menu for this TreeItem is used, deactivate the menu
            setContextMenu(null);
        }
    }
    
    //Deccide if a menu should be shown or not
    private boolean showMenu(String t, boolean bln){
        if (t != null && !t.equals("Root")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }        

}

}
```

Comment: beware: cells are re-used - so you have to unset the contextMenu for cells that should not have one (f.i. if it is empty, or has null text or is root)

Comment: 100% right, TreeCells are dynamically created and re-used for speed-enhancement. This is due to the paradigm to separate GUI and data, which is quite rigorously implemented in JavaFX. The check if (t != null && !t.equals("Root")) in the example takes care of the cases you mentioned. However, one should be aware that one TreeCell (GUI) might be used for different TreeItems (Data).

Comment: actually, .. it doesn't ;) In your example, cells are _not_ reused (so the contextMenu is set exactly once). Change it to start with many items, remove enough to force re-use as empty and right-click on an empty row ..

Comment: Generate a tree with 10000 TreeItems and put the generated TreeCells in a HasMap. Print out the size of the HashMap on an action on the tree (e.g. click on ContextMenu). You will see, that there are around 10 to 20 TreeCells for 10000 TreeItems generated with the above example and new TreeCells are generated on demand - so they are reused with the example above. Obviously, one ContextMenu is generated for every TreeCell. When you don't want this, put the call for the ContextMenu constructor out of the TreeCell Object constructor. PS empty String is obviously not checked in the if statement.

Comment: what I meant (might not have been clear enough, sry): cells are certainly re-used - just not in this concrete example, where there's never a state change from not-empty to empty. Only in that state transition the basic error in your implementation (repeating one last time: missing nulling of the contextMenu) would show which is to _have_ a contextMenu for empty cells.

Comment: Ah ok, that's right, now I get your point. I will edit the code later to accommodate that.

Comment: Could you amend your example to show how I would have different menus for different TreeItems? I have code that uses TreeItem<SomeType> where SomeType has a reference in it as to what type of instance the class is and Id like to be able to assign a different menu to the TreeItem based on its type. Using a cell factory similar to what you have here, the factory doesn't differentiate between a TreeItem attached to the root or a TreeItem attached to that TreeItem - it puts the same meny on both of the TreeItems even though they are different SomeType instances.